# More shell scripts than one in one text file?

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, text

I am learning shell scripting for my introductory UNIX course at my university, and I`m curious if is it possible to have more than one shell script in one text file. What I mean by that is, for example in pascal when you have:

```
var…

begin
end.
//another program which will be ignore
```

compiler ignores anything after the end with period. Can something like this be done with Shell? I`m asking because I have to go through lot of Shell examples and having many files opened is not very handy, with this I could run the same script without worrying about u+x permissions and just run the script with same name anytime I go to the next code example.
So it is possible to have something that will say: end, do not read any further. ?
Thank you in anvance for answering this silly question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ul.sx! If you don't mind typing `exit` instead of `end.`, then yes, there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For said purpose - that is stopping the script at any given line - you could simply use `exit` to break at this point. For any real life application this would seem a little crude though but for learning purposes it should fit.

Say:

```
#!/bin/sh

# now I am working here
do_something
exit

# this is old, do not execute
did_something
exit

# this is even older, do not execute
did_something_long_ago
```

Comment: That is exactly what I`m looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the construction `: <<"SOMEWORD" ... SOMEWORD` which substitute the commenting by `#`

```
##### The following "code block" is effectively ignored
: <<"SOMEWORD"
/etc/init.d/mydatabase clean_stop
mydatabase_dump /var/db/db1 /mnt/fsrv0/backups/db1
logger -t SYSHALT "System halt: pre-shutdown actions done, now shutting down the system"
shutdown -h NOW
SOMEWORD
##### The ignored codeblock ends here
```